# What is the origin of "pompes funèbres" ?

Tags: sens, expressions

Where does "pompes funèbres" come from ?

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic: Please look up the meaning of words or expressions in a dictionary first. If you did so and found nothing satisfactory, mention that in your question. Do give context for where you heard or saw the word

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It comes directly from the Latin *Pompa funebris*.

*Pompa*, itself from the Greek *πομπή* meant a procession, a parade. We use a the related word *pompe* in French with the phrase *[en grandes pompe](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/en_grande_pompe)* (English inherited "pompous" from the French *[pompeux](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pompeux)*)

*Funebris* means related to funerals.

Three kinds of *pompa* (parades) in Rome were:

- the *pompa triumphalis* (to celebrate a militar victory)
- the *pompa funebris* (for a funeral)
- the *pompa circensis* (before circus "games").

Note also that there are other words sharing the same spelling and which are more common. The first one means "pump" (e.g. *pompe à essence* is "gas pump") and the second one is a slang word for shoe (e.g. *une paire de pompes*: a pair of kicks, *à coup de pompes*: kicking ass). There is also *faire des pompes*, i.e. to do push-ups and *avoir un coup de pompe*, to be exhausted (apparently from an early aviation term where *pompe* was used to mean the effect of air turbulence.)

There are also regional words like one meaning [some kinds of cakes](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pompe_%C3%A0_l%27huile_(dessert)) in Southern France and a slang word for cheat sheets.

Comment: *Pompe* is also the word for a *push-up*, presumably because the movement is similar to that of a pump.

Comment: ...and the slang phrase *avoir un coup de pompe* (if you think about it, that one makes no sense...)

Comment: @Greg Le coup de pompe, ce n’était pas à cause du baillement? C'est ainsi que je l'avais toujours compris, mais je me trompe peut-être...

Comment: @Feelew Pas à cause du bâillement mais de la fatigue causée par des successions de trous d'air (les coup de pompes) au début de l'aviation.

Comment: @jlliagre Bien vu!

Comment: *Pomper* is also a french slang verb for *giving a fellatio*, which leads to a famous French joke about how the term *pompes funèbres* appeared because the heir of a *croque-mort* (*undertaker*, but literally one that bites footfingers of dead people to verify if they are *really* dead) was his daughter, not his son.